# How to use localstorage value in get url in Angular 6?

Tags: angular

I want to get value from local storage and used that value in my request URL to get customer details in Angular 6.

login.component.ts

```
  OnLogin(){
     this.loginService.userLogin(this.username,this.password)
     .subscribe(
         data => {
         localStorage.setItem('AccountNo',data.AccountNo);
         }
  }
```

login.service.ts:

```
  getAccountNo(){
        return localStorage.getItem('AccountNo');
  }
```

checkout.service.ts:

```
  login1 = this.loginService.getAccountNo();

        async getAddress() {
            const address = await this.httpClient.get<Customer[]>('http://localhost:49422/api/customer/' + 'login1' +'/profile/', { withCredentials: true })
            .toPromise();
            return address;
        }
```

After the customer login, their details are maintained in local storage. I want to get the account number value from local storage and to be used in the URL in checkout service. How to achieve this? Is it possible to get the value from request header using interceptors? If it possible then how should achieve this?

Comment: 'login1.AccountNo' is invalid you might need to use login1 (without quotes) .make sure if login1 has a value  before making a httpRequest .

Comment: check the updated question. But how to use the login1 as without quotes. It is a url right?

Comment: `'http://localhost:49422/api/customer/' + login1 +'/profile/', { withCredentials: true }` if you add quotes to `login1` it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: It's working with small change..instead of login am using this.login

Comment: glad you're able to fix it .

Answer (score 3):

Can use like that,

```
 getAccountNo(){
        return localStorage.getItem('account_no');
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the **`same key`** which you have used for retrieval also

```
  return localStorage.getItem('account_no');
```

EDIT

you need to use just **`login1`** instead of **`'login1.AccountNo'`** in your request

Comment: I updated my question. I had use the same key value but am not getting the result

Comment: It shows error like Bad Request,http error response for this url.

Comment: i just need the value of login1

Comment: I can't get you.

Comment: Add a console.log(login1) and see what is the output

Comment: I did a mistake of giving the login1 with quotes in URL. That's the problem and it was resolved. Anyway thank you for your effort..